# Tem como passar o nome da função como parametro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui para uma solução cujo é passar nomes das funções como parâmetros para ser executado.

Tenho a função `ShowModal` no qual o objetivo dela é chamar outras funções e objetos. Como posso o nome da função para ela executar.

```
    $.showModal = function (idModal,idInputHidden,idNome,nameFunction,idOptional) {
    $(idModal).modal('show');
    if(idOptional == 'null'){
        $.setField(idInputHidden,idNome,idOptional);
    }else{
        $.nameFunction(idInputHidden,idNome);
    }
};

// Exemplo de uso Normal dela
$.showModal($('#myModalProduto'),$('#produto_modal_ctrl_id_key'),$('#produto_modal_ctrl_id'),'setFieldModalProduto',null);

//No Modal do Produto tenho a seguinte função setFieldModalProduto
$.setFieldModalProduto = function (a,b) {
            field1 =  $(a);
            field2 =  $(b);
        };
```

Comment: Para mim Não fico muito claro.

Comment: Passe a própria função na chamada, muito mais prático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por serem objetos de primeira classe, funções podem ser propriedades de objetos ou até mesmo arrays.

Se você não definiu a quem a função pertence (objeto ou outra variável) ela pertencerá ao objeto `window`:

```js
function chamaOutra(nome_funcao, parametro){
  window[nome_funcao](parametro);
}

function myAlert(parametro){
   alert(parametro);
}

chamaOutra("myAlert", "Teste 1");
```

Se você definiu a quem ela pertence, por exemplo, uma variável para agrupar as funções, basta informar a variável "pai" antes da função:

```js
   

var chamaOutra = function (nome_pai, nome_funcao, parametro){
  window[nome_pai][nome_funcao](parametro);
}

var mensagens = {}
mensagens.myAlert = function (parametro){
      alert(parametro);
}

chamaOutra("mensagens", "myAlert", "Teste 2");
```

[Nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/4921014), encontrei uma função que acredito que possa ser interessante para o seu caso:

```js
// lista com suas funções
var mensagens = {}
mensagens.myAlert = function (parametro){
      alert(parametro);
}

// função para chamar outras
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}

// chamando outra função
executeFunctionByName("mensagens.myAlert", window, "Teste 3");
```

Como comentado por @bfavaretto, você também pode passar como argumento, porém neste caso, você não poderá usar uma string como parâmetro:

```js
// lista de funções 
var  myAlert = function(my_parametro){
   alert(my_parametro);
}

// função para chamar outras
function chamaOutras(funcao, parametro){
    if(typeof(funcao)=="function"){
        funcao.call();
    }
}

// chamando outras
chamaOutras(myAlert("Teste 4"));
```

Comment: Por serem objetos de primeira classe, também podem ser passadas como argumento. O que é preferível a passar o nome.

Comment: Vou verificar flw!

Comment: Funcionou a resposta acima?

Comment: Sim, já marquei vc como respondido. Obrigado mais uma vez.